# how to store values of type <T>

Tags: c++, arduino

How to store values of datatype `<T>`? What I'm trying to do is to have a function that will work for `long` or `double` types. For example, to return median of 5 numbers (because now I have two classes, one for long, one for double). Two things I do not know how to:

- how to store `<T>` values
- is it possible to call function with return type `<T>` from function of return type `<T>`

This is non/working code, stripped to be readable. The code is for Arduino (or other similar microcontrolers). Thank you.

```
//how to store custom type?
//in practice, this may be a single value, array,
//or struct with one of the members being T

T values[5]={2,6,8,9,11};

//public
template <typename T> T getFirst (){
  T result = getPos[0]; 
  return result;  
}

//private
template <typename T> T getPos (byte index){
  T result = values[index]; 
  return result;  
}

void setup() {
  // put your setup code here, to run once:
  double k;
  k=getFirst()
}

void loop() {
  // put your main code here, to run repeatedly:

}
```

---

**EDIT 4,** THE FINAL THOUGHTS:
Since some users reported too many edits, I've decided to delete all of it. I've left only the original question. I will give my final findings in a new, separate anwser.

Comment: Have you considered `std::vector<T> values;`? The answer to the second question is `yes`

Comment: As you have not posted the whole code, this might not be the actual issue. But there are two things not working: Firs getPos is private which might cause visibility issues. Second getFirst and getPos cannot derive their typename by the arguments you give to the function. Try: getFirst<double>() and accordingly: getPost<T>[0]. Also values does not know what type to use, I suppose you have a solution for that somewhere in your code?

Comment: @GMichael for arduino devices I generally would recommend against using STL container. Depending on the application it might be worthwhile, but usually the overhead is significant and on microcontrollers, that might be more important than convenience.

Comment: @FreddyKay for now, we may ignore visibility issues. Your question of "how do values know they type" is actually question asked, so - no - I don't know, that's what I want to find out. :)

Comment: You should store the type that comes as the input. Are you using this class for both long and double input streams?

Answer (score 1):

**Edit** this answer is no longer relevant since the question has been changed considerably. (End edit)

A function that computes a median of 5 values needs to get 5 values as an argument. This could be a standard container or a plain pointer to a legacy array or a pair of iterators. The function doesn't need to be concerned with storage of these values. The caller stores them.

```
template <typename T>
T median_of_5 (const std::array<T, 5>&); // a standard no-overhead container

template <typename T>
T median_of_5 (const T*); // a legacy array

template <typename Iter>
decltype(*std::declval<Iter>())
median_of_5 (Iter first, Iter last); // two iterators

// or another way
template <typename Iter>
typename std::iterator_traits<Iter>::value_type
median_of_5 (Iter first, Iter last); // two iterators
```

If a function template needs temporary storage for some data of type T, just declare it in the function:

```
template <typename T>
T median_of_5 (const std::array<T, 5>&)
{
    T values[5]; // no problem here
    ...
}
```

On the off chance you need to actually store five values outside of any function template using a generic type T, and you can use C++14, you can use a variable template:

```
 template <typename T>
 T values[5] { 2,6,8,9,11 };
```

But this is most probably not what you need.

Comment: Aren't variable templates a concept in C++17?

Comment: Well, I actuall do have a function that returns median, I can post that, but it's a bit longer. But my problem is - I now have class for calculating median for each type - for long, for double, for byte.... I just believe that I can have ONE function that does that, with variable type. So I can have only one function. I hope its much cleaner now. Also, I'm not sure if I can use STD in arduino.

Comment: @nekitip yes you can have one function template that returns a median of 5. I gave you several examples of how such a template might look like. However that's not what you arw asking in your question. You are asking about storage. Consider asking directly about what you really need, rather than about some related concept that you think might help you getting what you really need. "I have three nearly identical functions that compute median of five, only types are different. How can I stop duplicating code?"

Comment: As for the standard library on Arduino, I'm not sure. I hear there's a port of uClibc++ for it. It is however in no way required to use templates.

Comment: @n.m. I appologise if I was not clear asking what I need, so I've included the whole class. The question remains the same - how to store values of T. I've tried adding template <typename T>
 T values[5] { 2,6,8,9,11 };, to the FIRST example, but it does not work somehow.

Comment: @nekitip I don't understand. Your entire issue was with code duplication, and you have actually removed the duplication before showing the code. I can't solve a problem I can't see.

Comment: @Zereges variable templates are from C++14. Inline variables are what will come with C++17.

Answer (score 1):

Do you mean something like this?

```
template<typename T>
class medianbuffer{
public:
    // Should work like this
    medianbuffer() { /**/ }
    ~medianbuffer() { /**/ } // "~" = destructor , no expecting to happen
    T getFirst (){
        T result = getPos(0);
        return result;
    }
    private:
    T getPos (byte index){
        T result = values[index];
        return result;
    }
    T values[5]={2,6,8,9,11};
};
```

All function using the template typename will have to be defined in the header file AFAIK.

You will then have one medianbuffer class per type that you use. All functions still need a definition.

Comment: great anwser, it showed me what I missed in anwser by n.m.! Please, take a look at EDIT 2, since it's only a small bit missing!

Comment: what is the error you get on the constructor and destructor?

Comment: in EDIT 2, it is: undefined reference to `medianbuffer<double>::medianbuffer()' AND undefined reference to `medianbuffer<double>::~medianbuffer()', (this is for each type.. the same is for INT type., and in the version with complete code, it is at position of class constructor and destructor medianbuffer::medianbuffer(){
}
medianbuffer::~medianbuffer(){
}

Comment: I edited my answer to that. Make sure you have an actual definition for the constructor and destructor.

Comment: now your last anwser works prefectly! However, I'm still missing something in constructor /destructor of .cpp file, on line: #include "medianbuffer.h"

medianbuffer::medianbuffer(){/**/}
medianbuffer::~medianbuffer(){/**/}

//problem of adding to circular buffer is that if sorting is done after each add

Comment: Sorry I do not understand the problem. If it is the same as posted in EDIT 3, then you will have to define your fuctions in the .h file every time you make use of any templated member.

Answer (score 0):

So, here are some findings that I have now.

- before trying everything you can find online, first create new class, and play with it. Trying to use type of `<T>` works better or only this way (do not know when).
- do not use separate files for .h and .cpp. I'm not sure why is this a problem, since compiler is after all "merging" all of the files together anyway, but it turns out that if you do not follow this advide you will get errors that smart people can understand - but you will not, and there goes - two days are wasted.

At the moment of writing this, this is all that I know. My guess that in following years, a lot of people may stumble here, and that the ones who know better try to give some better explaned anwsers, or at least fill the gaps.

```
/*Before class with prototypes, indicate that Template T will be used
   not sure when to use first or second line, seems that both work in this scenario*/
    //template<class  T>
    template<typename  T>
    class medianbuffer{
        public:    
        medianbuffer() { /**/ } //since no cpp will be used, do not forget to create proper functions {} in this file
        ~medianbuffer() { /**/ } 
        T getFirst();
        //you may also try to define it here
        //T getFirst();{
           // T result = getPos(1);
           // return result;
        //}
        private:
        T getPos (byte index){
            T result = values[index];
            return result;
        }
        T values[5]={2,6,8,9,11};
    };

    //Here is one of your bigest time waste, and it's not an obvious one - put all in one file!
    /*The following part is usually in cpp files, but you will see a lot of "undefined" or similar warnings
    Because templates are compiled when required, this forces a restriction for multi-file projects:
    the implementation (definition) of a template class or function must be in the same file as its declaration.
    That means that we cannot separate the interface in a separate header file,
    and that we must include both interface and implementation in any file that uses the templates.
    http://www.cplusplus.com/doc/oldtutorial/templates/
    */
    //if writing methods here, remember that every method must have "template" in front,
    //do not forget to put <T>, since you will get a lot of cryptic errors
    template<typename  T>
    T medianbuffer<T>::getFirst(){
        T result = getPos(1);
        return result;
    }

    //type of T is actually passed to its class this way
    medianbuffer <double>mb_d;
    medianbuffer <int> mb_i;

    void setup() {
        Serial.begin(57600);
        debug();
    }

    void debug(){

        //class instantiated as double, you can use it normaly
        double first_d=mb_d.getFirst();
        Serial.print("\n double type --> ");
        Serial.print(first_d);

        //class instantiated as int
        int first_i=mb_i.getFirst();
        Serial.print("\n int type    --> ");
        Serial.print(first_i);
    }
    void loop() {
        // put your main code here, to run repeatedly:

    }
```

Thanks n.m. and FredyKay, your help was very appreciated.